# Save existing Docker stack to reapply it

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

We are running Docker in swarm mode. Is it possible to save an existing Docker stack to reapply it in case the whole cluster would be destroyed?

If Docker would save the docker-compose file anywhere, we could backup this file but I dind't find any indication in the Docker docu that this would be the case.

Comment: Usually you'd keep the `docker-compose.yml` file and similar deployment artifacts in source control.  Then there's not a need to "back them up" _per se_, you can just check out the repository and redeploy.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your answer. I agree with you. In this case the problem is our customers apply and mange their docker-compose.yml and we only provide the infrastructure (Docker swarm nodes)

Answer (score 0):

Gitops is more known in the kubernetes space than the Docker space, but a common way of managing this is:

- maintain your desired state (in this case, stack.yml files) in a git repo.
- use commit hooks to deploy changes automatically.

Traditional GitOps solutions like ArgoCD target K8s rather than Docker, so you need to do a bit more work. Consider the following:

- Portainer.io has a beta feature to deploy stack.ymls to swarm.
- Gitlab-ce / Jenkins can be used to setup CI/CD pipelines that trigger on commits and use docker based runners to publish.
- GitHub actions if you are in the public cloud.

Comment: github actions is available for private repos too

Comment: point taken, but I meant more to imply that the target infrastructure was reachable from a cloud based pipeline.